# Which ECMAScript Version can I use in Adobe Animate CC

Tags: javascript, animation, adobe, ecmascript-6

I am kinda confused which version Animate CC supports.

ActionScript 3 is based on ECMAScript 4 as far as I know.

Is it possible to use ES6 and/or Standard JS libs?
(Would it be possible to use Animate CCs Animation Tooling with GSAP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe animate supports the current JavaScript from your browser , generally is ES5 , if you want work with ES6 you should use a transpilator like babel, but you will need other tools like NodeJs - npm, Webpack.

This video is a reference to install webpack + adobe animate, is in Spanish https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rDdvltHxurA

Maybe in future versions Adode Animate will support a transpilator ES6.